# Align hover tooltip to always be centered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a bunch of image thumbnails that when hovered will be displayed in full size in a tooltip. I've based it on [this demo](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/) and it works fine.

*However*, I want the full size image to be displayed centered underneath its thumbnail regardless of image size. As it is now my full size image aligns its left side underneath the tooltip. I've been playing around with the `offset` values but I can't get it to work.

[I've created a fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/o6tkm85j/)

Thanks!

**My JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    xOffset = -50;
    yOffset = 0;

    $("a.preview").hover(function (e) {
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<div id='preview'><div class='arrow'></div><img src='" + this.href + "' alt='Image preview' />" + c + "</div>");
        $("#preview")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");
    },

    function () {
        this.title = this.t;
        $("#preview").remove();
    });
    $("a.preview").mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#preview")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });
});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/220x165" class="preview"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/520x130" class="preview"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As it is now my full size image aligns its left side underneath the
>   tooltip.

That is because, your tooltip is absolutely positioned, and you are calculating the `left` property from  `e.pageX` adding a fixed offset of `0px`;

> I want the full size image to be displayed centered underneath its
>   thumbnail regardless of image size

What you can quickly do is, to calculate the `left` property by decreasing the half of the width of your tooltip. You can calculate the width of the tooltip using `.outerWidth()` method.

*Instead of this*:

```
$("#preview")
    .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
    .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
    .fadeIn("fast");
```

*Reduce the half of the width*:

```
var w = $("#preview").outerWidth();
$("#preview")
    .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
    .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset  - (w/2)) + "px")
    .fadeIn("fast");
```

***Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/o6tkm85j/1/***

.

Answer (score 1):

For showing it just centered under the thumbnail, you need to take care of one more variable that you were missing out i.e. ***`#preview` width***. Just decrease half the width of the `#preview` from ***`#preview` left***. Then you will have it just under the thumbnail.

```
var width1 = $("#preview").width() / 2;
$("#preview")
    .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
    .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset - width1) + "px")
    .fadeIn("fast");
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6tkm85j/2/)**